# HTML5 video tag replay event

Tags: jquery, html, video

I have html code like below

```
<div id="#p0">
<div style="width:1320px;height:1080px;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:0;">
    <video preload="auto" autoplay>
            <source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="1.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>
<div style="width:600px;height:1080px;position:absolute;left:1321px;top:0px;z-index:0;">
    <video preload="auto" autoplay>
            <source src="2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="2.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>
<div style="width:1000px;height:600px;position:absolute;left:200px;top:200px;z-index:5;">
    <video preload="auto" autoplay>
            <source src="3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="3.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>
</div>
```

First time i am creating  video tag and appending to main div but from next onwards i am just playing video using display show hide but I want to get duration of video everytime but below code is calling once only.

```
this.addEventListener('loadeddata', function(e) {
        e.target.duration
   });
```

Comment: this code is simply `html` ! how do you create and append video tag? In html you can write `var duration=null; this.addEventListener('loadeddata', function(e) {
        duration = e.target.duration
   }); alert('duration');`

Comment: yeah but this addEventListener is called when you load video but from next onwards ,i am playing video only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure JavaScript it is not easy because by definition, `.loadeddata` runs once in the User Agent...

Since I can see you have "`jQuery`-tagged" your question, I may suggest you use this piece of code

```
 var video = $('#videoID')[0];
  video.onloaddata = function(e) { /* your code here*/ };
```

Voilà!

Comment: You also have `.onloadeddata ` etc.